# Unexpected results from using 2 consecutive fgets in C

Tags: c, fgets

```
int main()
{

    char firstdate[10];
    char seconddate[10];    

    printf("Enter the First Date in this format:DD/MM/YYYY\n");
    fgets(firstdate , 11 , stdin);
    printf("Check: %s\n" , firstdate);



    printf("Enter the second Date in this format:DD/MM/YYYY\n");

    fgets(seconddate , 11 , stdin);
    printf("Check: %s\n" , seconddate);


    printf("second Check: %s\n" , firstdate);
    printf("second Check: %s\n" , seconddate);

    return 0;

}
```

Its a fairly simple program for now. As I expected, after the first call to `fgets()`, the input was stored in the char array `firstdate`. But after the second call to `fgets()`, the value in the `firstdate` char array seems to have gone missing. Not sure what is going on or why I get such results. Can you help me?

Results:

```
Enter the First Date in this format:DD/MM/YYYY
10/01/1997
Check: 10/01/1997

Enter the second Date in this format:DD/MM/YYYY
20/04/1995
Check: 20/04/1995

second Check:
second Check: 20/04/1995
```

Whats weird is that even though the array was too small to hold the contents, it initially was able to hold it correctly (As seen by the first output). 
Calling the second fgets function got rid of the value in 'firstdate' variable

Comment: You are writting out of bounds of your arrays. You should change the size of your arrays to 11.

Comment: @Appatakardot What result are you expecting after this call  fgets(firstdate , 11 , stdin); taking into account this declaration char firstdate[10];?

Comment: Change `char firstdate[10];` -> `char firstdate[11];` and `char seconddate[10]; ` -> `char seconddate[11]; `

Comment: Both `firstdate` and `seconddate` arrays have space for 10 bytes. Yet you're telling `fgets` they have 11. Next problem would be the newline left in by `fgets()` calls. Also see: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: @Appatakardot Never use magic numbers. They are reasons for program bugs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your `char[]` are too small to hold what you read:**

```
char firstdate[10]; // array of 10 bytes
fgets(firstdate, 11, stdin); // read 11 bytes
```

And, from `fgets()`'s man page:

> Reading stops when a newline character is found, at end-of-file or error. The newline, if any, is retained. If any characters are read and there is no error, a `\0' character is appended to end the string.

**So you should declare arrays of size 13 and read 12 bytes (until a `'\n'` is found):**

```
char firstdate[13];
char seconddate[13];
fgets(firstdate, 12, stdin);
fgets(seconddate, 12, stdin);
```

Comment: No need to read one less than the size, as `fgets` already does that for you.  The man page states: *"fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream"*

Comment: i chose to read 11 bytes from the stream because when i chose to read 10 bytes instead, clicking the enter button for the first input resulted in the program totally disregarding the second fgets function. Choosing to read 11 bytes solved this issue but had new problems as stated above

Comment: Better to use `sizeof firstdate` and `sizeof seconddate` instead of the literal `12` in the `fgets` calls.